# How to ensure that FindClusters and ClusterClassify have the same cluster name?

Tags: labeling, cluster-analysis

I am trying to ensure that both the `FindCluster` and `ClusterClassify` function provide the **same** cluster name.

To explain this better, I have a minimum working example in which dummy data is organized into 4 clusters.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
dummydata = 
  RandomSample[
   Table[x^2 + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}], {x, -1, 1, 0.002}]];
ListPlot[dummydata, PlotLabel -> "dummy data", 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize -> 0.02}]
```

### **fig 1: dummy data**

[image]

```
cdummy = FindClusters[dummydata, 4];
ListLinePlot[{cdummy[[1]], cdummy[[2]], cdummy[[3]], cdummy[[4]]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {PointSize -> 0.02}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabel -> "dummy data in 4 clusters"]
```

Notice the plot legend labeling  for the 4 clusters.

### **fig 2: dummy data organized into 4 clusters**

[image]

Classifying the dummy data into 4 clusters so that given any data point, I know what cluster it belongs to.

```
cdummyClassify = ClusterClassify[dummydata, 4]
{cdummyClassify[0.92], cdummyClassify[0.99], cdummyClassify[0.52], 
 cdummyClassify[0.55], cdummyClassify[0.02]}
```

Now, I create a cluster classification object which would allow me to identify the data cluster any given point in the future belongs to.

```
cdummyClassify = ClusterClassify[dummydata, 4]
{cdummyClassify[0.92], cdummyClassify[0.99], cdummyClassify[0.52], 
 cdummyClassify[0.55], cdummyClassify[0.02]}
```

Although the classification of data points is correct, the cluster label is not the same as that of fig 2.  How do I ensure that the same clustering label is used for both `FindClusters` and `ClusterClassify`?

```
(*{2, 2, 4, 4, 1}*)
```